# DateTime value changes after I post it on server and then receive it back

Tags: asp.net, date, datetime, time, xamarin.forms

I use `DateTime.Now` method to get local time on machine and then post it with model to ASP.NET server.

The `DateTime` value I post is:

[image: The DateTime value i post]

The `DateTime` value I get from server is:

[image: The DateTime value i get from server]

So as you can see in the screenshots two values are different. My problem is that they should be the same.

Post method on ASP.Net server:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostTimeCap(TimeCap timeCap)
{
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        List<TimeCap> l = db.TimeCaps.ToList();
        TimeCap lastCap;

        if (l.Count > 0)
        {
            lastCap = l[l.Count - 1];

            for (int i = l.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                if (l[i].userind == timeCap.userind && lastCap.date < l[i].date && !l[i].isPairDefined)
                {
                    lastCap = l[i];
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            lastCap = null;
        }

        if (timeCap.typeOfCap == "open")
        {
        }
        else if(timeCap.typeOfCap == "overwork")
        {
        }
        else if(timeCap.typeOfCap == "close")
        {
            if (lastCap != null)
            {
                if (lastCap.typeOfCap == "open" || lastCap.typeOfCap == "overwork")
                {
                    timeCap.isPairDefined = true;
                    timeCap.pairIndex = lastCap.id;
                    lastCap.isPairDefined = true;
                    await PutTimeCap(lastCap.id, lastCap);
                    double totalSec = (timeCap.date - lastCap.date).TotalSeconds;
                    totalSec = totalSec / 3600;
                    timeCap.workhours = (float)totalSec;
                }
                else
                {
                    //DeleteTimeCap(lastCap.id);
                    //TimeCap lc = FindLastCap(timeCap.userind);
                    //timeCap.isPairDefined = true;
                    //timeCap.pairIndex = lc.id;
                }
            }
        }

        db.TimeCaps.Add(timeCap);
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();

        return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = timeCap.id }, timeCap);
}
```

Get method on the server:

```
public IQueryable<TimeCap> GetTimeCaps()
{
    return db.TimeCaps;
}
```

On the client:

```
TimeCap t = new TimeCap
            {
                date = DateTime.Now,
                typeOfCap = "overwork",
                userind = DataStaticStorage.userId,
                isPairDefined = false,
                isVerifyed = false,
                pairIndex = 0,
                imgIndex = imgstr,
                workhours = 0f
            };
```

And when I get from server:

```
t.dateStr = tp[i].date.ToString("F");
```

I need to post a datetime and then receive it back without changes.

Do I miss a big shard of knowledge about `DateTime` and Asp.net?

My local time is GMT +6 (Kazakhstan, Astana)

Comment: you are sending a Local DateTime, and the server is returning an Unspecified DateTime.  To eliminate confusion it's generally best to create the client DateTime as UTC, not Local.

Comment: Ok now I get it. I post DateTime like this: DateTime now = DateTime.UtcNow and  I get it like this: response.date.ToLocalTime() and its working like I want it to. Thank you Jason, this site is real help ; )

Comment: Hello, @ДарханСыдыков! I had the same issue. It is because of different formats of datetime. You have to set format for your datetime without milliseconds.